# Parsing dates that can have varying formats

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse a nullable datetime which contains a date and a string which is the time. I would like to be able to put the datetime and the time string together to parse a datetime. But the time and date could be in a inconsistent format. Here is what I have come up with but it breaks for certain formats:

```
private DateTime? ParseToDateTime(DateTime? dateTime, string time)
{
    if (dateTime.HasValue)
    {
        //Parse the time

        time = TimeToParse(time);
        if (TimeValid(time))
        {
            var inptTime = time.PadLeft(4, '0');
            var hrs = int.Parse(inptTime.Left(2));
            var mins = int.Parse(inptTime.Right(2)) + hrs * 60;
            return DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime.Value.Date.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(mins)), DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private string TimeToParse(string time)
{
    if (time.Contains("+"))
    {
        time = time.Substring(0, time.IndexOf("+", StringComparison.Ordinal));
    }
    return time;
}

private static bool TimeValid(string time) 
{ 
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(time)) return false; 
     if (time.Length < 4) return false; 
     if (time.Length > 4) return false; 
     return true; 
}
```

I looked into tryparse exact also but the format could be different and we are talking two different values here any idea?

Comment: You are not giving any examples; how are we supposed to know how to parse it?

Comment: forgot         private static bool TimeValid(string time)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(time)) return false;
            if (time.Length < 4) return false;
            if (time.Length > 4) return false;
            return true;
        }

Comment: Sorry here are some examples :

datetime = 2016-04-23, 23-12-2016, 17/10/2016
time = 23:59, 2359, 23359, 2359+1, 350

Comment: You can use `DateTime.Parse` to convert your time string to DateTime. I don't understand why are you manually parsing and converting it to minutes...

Comment: Title of your post caught my attention!

Comment: I have tried DateTime.Parse() but this doesn't parse on 2359

Comment: @RBT yes, let's not devolve into clickbait titles.

Comment: Of course...2359 is not a valid time :) But if you are going to get time in that format always, you could try `DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(time,"HHmm",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Your question is currently unanswerable, see duplicate for the idiomatic way: using `DateTime.TryParseExact(string, string[], ...)` where you can pass multiple acceptable formats. If you insist on reinventing the wheel, then elaborate on _"it breaks for certain formats"_ and create a [mcve] including example input and how exactly it "breaks".

Comment: you are saying - `But the time and date could be in a inconsistent format`. How is that possible? I can understand that `time` parameter is an string so it can be in inconsistent format but why `dateTime` parameter can be in inconsistent format?

Comment: In your `TimeToParse` function you are making a check for `+` character which can come in input which means you know that `+` can come in your input? Do you know what all possible weird formats are possible which can come in input for `time` parameter? Please add a few sample inputs.

Comment: Same inputs for time :

12:59+1
1259
0203

tried this TimeSpan.TryParseExact(time.Trim().Replace("+", "").Replace(":", ""), new[] { "HH:mm", "HHmmss" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                TimeSpanStyles.None, out t)) which didn't work for 2359 or 23:59